# Chromium doesn't play nice with themes in Debian XFCE

Tags: themes, chromium, debian-wheezy

[image]I've found that Chromium seems to ignore any of the themes I have on my Debian Wheezy running XFCE as its DE. More specifically, its window always looks exactly the same (blue bar, for example) regardless of what theme I'm running. Is there a way to work around this?

Edit: As per request, I have added a screenshot illustrating the problem.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot please?

Comment: @joejoe31b: As per request, one screenshot. I have my terminal and a Thunar window open in front of Chromium for comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

This isn't a bug or a glitch. What you are seeing is the titlebar that was programmed into Chromium. From what I read [HERE](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/233/disable-titlebar-for-chrome-and-chromium-browsers/), it is very easy to disable. You can disable it and force it to use the default system theme by ticking `Use system title bar and borders` under `Appearance` in the Settings window (which you can access by typing `chrome://settings` in the address bar).

Comment: I have done this but in xfce this makes my buttons disappear.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot I could look at?

Comment: Here are the images: http://imgur.com/a/sVnjv. Thanks for your help. Sorry it took so long.